# Restricting FCM credentials to only development apps

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I work on several Android and iOS apps with a team of developers. These apps use Push Notifications - through Firebase (FCM) for Android and through APNs for iOS.

For APNs, we use a key (`.p8` file) for production servers, and a sandbox-only certificate (`.pem` file) for testing. Our development team is allowed to use the sandbox for testing push notifications, but cannot accidentally send push notifications to production.

For FCM, we use a Service Account (`.json` file) for production servers, and we want a way to allow our developers to test push notifications in development without being able to push messages to production.

We have configured our Android apps so that debug builds append `.dev` to the application ID, like this:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        }
    }
}
```

In the Firebase console, our project contains both app identifiers `com.example.myapp` (not the real name) and `com.example.myapp.dev` as separate apps.

However, I cannot find a way to create a separate Service Account that is limited to sending to the `.dev` apps.

Is there a way that I can set up a development-only account so my developers can send push notifications only to the development versions of the apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario the only thing I can think would be creating a new Firebase project in order to isolate both environments.

I'm not aware of a way to restrict a service account from sending FCM messages to only a particular app in the project.